# Django: what do model and fields do in meta class?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am following the Django tutorial series from "trydjango: coding for enterpreneurs", and was confused about what "model" and "field" do in a Django form.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class SignUp(models.Model):
    email=models.EmailField()
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import SignUp

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=SignUp   # ?
        fields=['full_name','email']  # ?

    def clean_email(self):
        email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_base,provider=email.split("@")
        domain,extension=provider.split(".")
        if not domain == 'USC':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please make sure you use your USC email")
        if not extension == "edu":
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please use valide edu address")
        return email

    def clean_full_name(self):
        full_name = self.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
        #write validation code
        return full_name
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a special Form class which allows you to create a new Form auto-magically from the specified Model class. For more refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Model field shows which Model your Form would be created from and Fields field shows which fields from the Model class to show in your new Form.